# How to get all the request headers of a jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get all the request headers that I have set after an ajax call is made. My authorization and a few other headers vary for each call and it is a pain to keep track of all of them. In the $( document ).ajaxComplete(), the xhr and the settings do not seem to have the request headers. There are the whole response headers though. Is there a way wherein I can get all the request headers after I pass the request (in the ajaxcomplete)?